# SQlite Query using WHERE clause is not giving me the right output when I use a Tkinter drop down box

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm trying to create a button that can filter students by their levels. For some reason, SQlite is not querying the data I want, instead, it gives me an empty list ([]). When I don't use a drop down box and simply use an Entry box, it works fine.

```
#dropdown
levels = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]
drop = StringVar()
drop.set(levels[0])
def levelsfunc(event):
    levelsinfo = clickedsub2.get()
dropdownbox = OptionMenu(root, drop, *levels, command=levelsfunc)
#search function
def filterstudents():
    query = "SELECT studentname, level FROM studenttable WHERE level = '%"+dropdown.get()+"%'"
    c.execute(query)
    filtered = c.fetchall()
    print(filtered)
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `dropdown.get()` is returning what you think it should be returning?

Comment: Dropdown.get() returns the value that I select from the dropdown box. I have also tried passing it through a variable but it still does not work

Comment: I know what `dropdown.get()` is _supposed_ to do. Have you _verified_ that it's doing what you expect? The first step when debugging is always to verify that variables hold what you think they hold. You should modify `filterstudents` to print out the exact query being run. That will  likely give you a clue.

Comment: Given that you're calling `dropdown.get()` but the code you posted has nothing named `dropdown`, it's going to be hard for us to provide any useful answers.

Comment: There is no `dropdown`, only `drop` (`StringVar`) or `dropdownbox` (`OptionMenu`).  I think `drop` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` characters are wildcards and they are used when you also use the operator `LIKE`:

```
query = "SELECT studentname, level FROM studenttable WHERE level LIKE '%" + dropdown.get() + "%'"
```

This query will return all the rows that contain in the column `level` the value of the string `dropdown.get()`.

Or better use a `?` placeholder:

```
query = "SELECT studentname, level FROM studenttable WHERE level LIKE '%' || ? || '%'"
c.execute(query, (dropdown.get(),))
```

Comment: I also tried `WHERE oid = ?", (dropdown.get(),))` and I still does not give me the right list

Comment: @JohnDorf then `dropdown.get()` does not return the correct values or the value that it returns does not exist in the table. Did you debug to examine the value returned by `dropdown.get()`?

Comment: @JohnDorf The query seems fine, must be some problem with the old code.